# Can you easily calculate work done by a force when you have force as a function of time?

Tags: forces, work

Can you easily calculate work done by a force when you have force as a function of time rather than force as a function of displacement?

In my textbook, it says the following:

> If an object is moved in a straight line from a position $x_1$ to a
> position $x_2$ by the action of a variable force $f(x)$ that depends
> on displacement, $x$, work done is defined as
>
> $$\text{work done} = \displaystyle\int_ {x_1} ^ {x_2} f(x) dx $$

$$$$

In a problem I came up with (so not a part of the textbook), I am interested in finding the work done on an object of mass $4,000\ kg$ with acceleration $a(t) = \frac{5}{32}\left(1-\frac{1}{16}t\right)\ ms^{-1},\ $ so the force is $F(t) = 1875\left(1-\frac{t}{16}\right),\ 0\leq t \leq 32\ $ where $t$ is time in seconds.

In the context of the original problem, the displacement, $x(t)$, was found by integrating $a(t)$ twice, and applying conditions $v(t=0) = 0$ and $x(t=0)=0.$ I got: $x(t) = \frac{15}{32}\left(\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t^3}{96}\right).$ The next natural step would be to rearrange and find $t$ in terms of $x$ and then  write $F$ in terms of $x,$ and then simply use the above formula. But finding the inverse [seems a bit gross](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1483839/) and even if we figure this out, integrating it seems like it will lead to even uglier/more difficult maths. Is my assessment correct, and is there an alternative method to find the work done by the force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$W\equiv\int_{\vec r_i}^{\vec r_f}\vec F\cdot d\vec r = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\left(\vec F(t)\cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}\right)dt,$$
where, just to be completely clear, $\vec r(t_i)=\vec r_i$ and $\vec r(t_f)=\vec r_f$.  For possibly more information/insight, take a look at line integrals in a more formal mathematical context; the work done is the line integral of the force along the path.

In your case, the problem is 1D, so the dot product is simply multiplication.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.